# Ansible stop the whole playbook if all hosts in a single play fail

Tags: ansible

I'm struggling to understand what's the intended behavior of ansible in case all hosts fail in a single play but there are other plays on other hosts in the playbook.

For example consider the following playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: P1
  hosts: a,b
  tasks:
    - name: Assert 1
      ansible.builtin.assert:
        that: 1==2
      when: inventory_hostname != "c"

- name: P2
  hosts: y,z
  tasks:
    - name: Debug 2
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: 'YZ'
```

All 4 hosts `a,b,y,z` point to `localhost` for the sake of clarity.

What happens is `assert` fails and the whole playbook stops. However it seems to contradict the documentation which says that in case of an error ansible stops executing on the failed host but continues on the other hosts, see [Error handling](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html)

In case I change the condition to `when: inventory_hostname != 'b'` and therefore `b` does not fail then the playbook continues to execute the second play on hosts `y,z`.

To me the initial failure does not seem reasonable because the hosts `y,z` have not experience any errors and therefore execution on them should not be prevented by the error on the other hosts.

Is this is a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a bug. It's by design (see Notes 3,4 below). As discussed in the comments to the other answer, the decision whether to terminate the whole playbook when all hosts in a play fail or not seems to be a trade-off. Either a user will have to handle how to proceed to the next play if necessary or how to stop the whole playbook if necessary. You can see in the examples below that both options require handling errors in a block approximately to the same extent.

- The first case was implemented by Ansible: A playbook will terminate when all hosts in a play fail. For example,

```yaml
- hosts: host01,host02
  tasks:
    - assert:
        that: false
- hosts: host03
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Hello
```

```yaml
PLAY [host01,host02] *************************************************************************

TASK [assert] ********************************************************************************
fatal: [host01]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: false
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: Assertion failed
fatal: [host02]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: false
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: Assertion failed

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host01                     : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host02                     : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

- The playbook will proceed to the next play when not all hosts in a play fail. For example,

```yaml
- hosts: host01,host02
  tasks:
    - assert:
        that: false
      when: inventory_hostname == 'host01'
- hosts: host03
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Hello
```

```yaml
PLAY [host01,host02] *************************************************************************

TASK [assert] ********************************************************************************
fatal: [host01]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: false
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: Assertion failed
skipping: [host02]

PLAY [host03] ********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host03] => 
  msg: Hello

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host01                     : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host02                     : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host03                     : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

- To proceed to the next play when all hosts in a play fail, a user has to clear the errors, and, optionally, end the host in a play as well. For example,

```yaml
- hosts: host01,host02
  tasks:
    - block:
        - assert:
            that: false
      rescue:
        - meta: clear_host_errors
        - meta: end_host
- hosts: host03
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Hello
```

```yaml
PLAY [host01,host02] *************************************************************************

TASK [assert] ********************************************************************************
fatal: [host01]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: false
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: Assertion failed
fatal: [host02]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: false
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: Assertion failed

TASK [meta] **********************************************************************************

TASK [meta] **********************************************************************************

TASK [meta] **********************************************************************************

PLAY [host03] ********************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host03] => 
  msg: Hello

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host01                     : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=1    ignored=0   
host02                     : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=1    ignored=0   
host03                     : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

- Update: The playbook can't be stopped by meta *end_play* after this was 'fixed' in [2.12.2](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.12/changelogs/CHANGELOG-v2.12.rst#id25).

It was possible to end the whole playbook by meta *end_play* in Ansible 2.12.1. Imagine that failed all hosts in a play wouldn't terminate the whole playbook. In other words, imagine it's not implemented that way. Then, a user might want to terminate the playbook on her own. For example,

```yaml
- hosts: host01,host02
  tasks:
    - block:
        - assert:
            that: false
      rescue:
        - meta: clear_host_errors
        - set_fact:
            host_failed: true
    - meta: end_play
      when: ansible_play_hosts_all|map('extract', hostvars, 'host_failed') is all
      run_once: true
- hosts: host03
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Hello
```

```yaml
PLAY [host01,host02] *************************************************************************

TASK [assert] ********************************************************************************
fatal: [host01]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: false
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: Assertion failed
fatal: [host02]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  assertion: false
  evaluated_to: false
  msg: Assertion failed

TASK [meta] **********************************************************************************

TASK [set_fact] ******************************************************************************
ok: [host01]
ok: [host02]

TASK [meta] **********************************************************************************

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host01                     : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=1    ignored=0   
host02                     : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=1    ignored=0
```

---

**Notes**

1. meta [*end_host*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html#parameters) means: 'end the play for this host'

```yaml
- hosts: host01
  tasks:
    - meta: end_host
- hosts: host01,host02
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Hello
```

```yaml
PLAY [host01] ********************************************************************************

TASK [meta] **********************************************************************************

PLAY [host01,host02] *************************************************************************

TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************
ok: [host01] => 
  msg: Hello
ok: [host02] => 
  msg: Hello

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
host01                     : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
host02                     : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

2. meta [*end_play*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/meta_module.html#parameters) means: 'end the playbook' (this was 'fixed' in 2.12.2. See [#76672](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/76672))

```yaml
- hosts: host01
  tasks:
    - meta: end_play
- hosts: host01,host02
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: Hello
```

```yaml
PLAY [host01] ********************************************************************************

TASK [meta] **********************************************************************************

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
```

3. Quoting from [#37309](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/37309#issuecomment-372532094)

> If all hosts in the current play batch (fail) the play ends, this is 'as designed' behavior ... 'play batch' is 'serial size' or all hosts in play if serial is not set.

4. Quoting from the [source](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/executor/playbook_executor.py#L200)

```py
# check the number of failures here, to see if they're above the maximum
# failure percentage allowed, or if any errors are fatal. If either of those
# conditions are met, we break out, otherwise, we only break out if the entire
# batch failed
failed_hosts_count = len(self._tqm._failed_hosts) + len(self._tqm._unreachable_hosts) - \
    (previously_failed + previously_unreachable)

if len(batch) == failed_hosts_count:
    break_play = True
    break
```

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer! `rescue` + `meta` looks like a promising workaround/solution!

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately, meta *end_play* is a 'moving target'. See [#76672](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/76672).

Answer (score 1):

A playbook with multiple play is just sequential, it cannot know in front that you are going to have any other hosts in a later play.

Because your `assert` task, in the first play, has exhausted all hosts of the play, it makes sense that the playbook stops there, as it won't have anything to do on any further tasks in `P1`, and remember, it doesn't know anything about `P2` yet, so it just end there.

Comment: I do not agree with the reasoning ``'Because your assert task in the first play has exhausted all hosts of the play, it makes sense that the playbook stops there'``. To stop a play? Yes. But, to stop a playbook? Why? ``'... it doesn't know anything about P2 yet, so it just ends there'`` Again why? The next play can proceed on other hosts.

Comment: Ansible execution is sequential, so how can the play know at the assertions in `tasks.0` that there is not going to be a `tasks.1`? Therefore, the play have exhausted all its hosts, have not yet discovered `P2` and stops.

Comment: And why, because it is the default strategy: [_Task execution is in lockstep per host batch as defined by serial (default all). Up to the fork limit of hosts will execute each task at the same time and then the next series of hosts until the batch is done, before going on to the next task._](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/linear_strategy.html#linear-strategy)

Comment: You're missing the point in both comments. Terminate a play? Yes. Terminate the whole playbook? Why? Instead, you keep talking about irrelevant subjects that happen inside a play ( strategy, serial, sequential, one task not knowing about other, ...). Focus on the question: *``Why shouldn't the next play proceed if all hosts in the previous play fail?``* In my answer, I added an example. I want to proceed to the next play no matter what. But, I have to clear the errors because the developers designed it that way. Probably because of some use-cases, I guess, but not because of logic.

Comment: It is because of the logic. Getting to this specific use case would means that for each task you will have to have a list of all the subsequent tasks still to execute and all the other plays, roles, include, you name it. Then evaluate that list to see if indeed, on top of the exhaustion of all hosts, there might not be something else that still makes a valid reason for the playbook to run. That would make it incredible slow.

Comment: In my last example, nothing is slow. But, I understand what you say: *``Letting the same hosts fail in the next play would be slow``*. Try to understand what I say: *``Either you have to handle how to proceed to the next play or how to stop the whole playbook``*. The first case was implemented. We do not know why.

Comment: You don't seems to get me either. I am not saying the rescuing of error would be slow, I am putting myself in a Python dev shoes. Now, you want to handle this case, how do you do it? You have to pre-process the whole YAML and list all the subsequent tasks delegated or other plays in the playbook so the fact that hosts exhaustion is not enough anymore? Wouldn't that slow the whole process of Ansible by a lot, in your opinion?

Comment: Still the same. The implementation dilemma was: ``Either the user will have to handle how to proceed to the next play if necessary or how to stop the whole playbook if necessary``. The first case was implemented: ``A playbook will terminate when all hosts in a play fail. A user will have to handle how to proceed to the next play if necessary.`` To complete the reasoning I added the example of how to stop a playbook.

Comment: It does not seem like going through all the remaining tasks would be that slow compared to actually executing these tasks. It can be considered inefficient which bring the point about the design philosophy already brought up above.

Comment: Given that playbooks are advertised as means to do multiple things on multiple groups of hosts it seems to me that it's a bit counterintuitive to terminate the whole playbook based on failure of a single play inside it. However it was good to learn how to get around it from the other answer.